# How to add localization support inside Flutter packages

Tags: flutter, localization, internationalization, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages

I am creating a Flutter package that has some text inside it. I want the consumer application of my package to pass locale to it, based on that locale my package should decide whether to show this text in 'Arabic' or 'English' (This means my package will have resource file containing strings inside it for these locales). **How can I achieve this?**

The only thing I was able to achieve was that my consumer application has the resource file and both my consumer application and package have to register the same localization plugin as dependency. I do not want my consumer app to worry about localization and instead my package should handle showing of translated strings based on locale. **Is there anything wrong with my approach?**

Comment: I have implemented the same by following what is done in another package - ```Catcher```. Here is the file - https://github.com/jhomlala/catcher/blob/master/lib/model/localization_options.dart

Comment: have you found nay solutions

Comment: @Braj how do yo implement it. any example

Answer (score 4):

Since then, Flutter team has introduced their own [localization support](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/accessibility-and-internationalization/internationalization). This answer aims to integrate official solution and adapting it into use for packages.

The key is to configure flutter l10n to generate output in out library package instead of `.dart_tool` by setting `synthetic_package: false` in `l10n.yaml`

1. Edit **l10n.yaml**

```yaml
arb-dir: lib/l10n
output-dir: lib/l10n
template-arb-file: app_en_hk.arb
output-localization-file: app_localizations.dart
nullable-getter: false
use-escaping: true
synthetic-package: false // this line
```

2. **Add `flutter_gen` in dev_dependencies ([ref](https://github.com/dart-lang/build/issues/2835)) in pubspec.yaml**, in addition to `build_runner`. I ran the command `flutter pub add flutter_gen --dev` in command line to ensure I get the newest available version.
3. **Execute following commands to generate the localization files**

```bash
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter gen-l10n # required command
dart run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

4. In your code where localization is needed, instead of importing `import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';`, **import `import 'package:<your_package>/l10n/app_localizations.dart';` instead.** Android Studio should be able to pick it up and offer quick fixes for this.
5. **When publishing, also include the generated l10n files** (i.e. `lib/l10n` in the above l10n.yaml)
6. Dependent apps will still need to include localization delegates in their `MaterialApp` constructor, as [instructed here](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/accessibility-and-internationalization/internationalization#adding-your-own-localized-messages). Particularly, **they will need to include your libraries' custom `AppLocalizations.delegate`.** Make this clear in your README Usage guides.

Comment: I don't think you need to add the flutter_gen package to the dependencies (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_gen). It is an unrelated package that coincidentally has the same name as the one generated automatically by build_runner.

Answer (score -1):

Your approach is on the right track, and it's common to use the flutter_localizations package for handling localization in Flutter. However, you can structure your package in a way that allows it to handle localization internally without requiring the consumer application to explicitly manage localization.

Here's a general guideline on how you can structure your package:

Define Localizations:
In your package, define a class that handles localization. This class can include methods to get the translated strings based on the provided locale.

```
    class MyPackageLocalizations {
  static const Map<String, Map<String, String>> _localizedStrings = {
    'en': {
      'hello': 'Hello',
    },
    'ar': {
      'hello': 'مرحبا',
    },
  };

  static String translate(String key, {String locale = 'en'}) {
    return _localizedStrings[locale]?.[key] ?? key;
  }
}
```

Expose a Localization Method:
Expose a method in your package that allows the consumer to set the locale. This method should be called from the consumer application.

```
class MyPackage {
  static String locale = 'en';

  static void setLocale(String newLocale) {
    locale = newLocale;
  }

  static String getHelloMessage() {
    return MyPackageLocalizations.translate('hello', locale: locale);
  }
}
```

Consumer Application:
In the consumer application, the developer only needs to call the setLocale method from your package to set the desired locale. Then, they can use the methods in your package to get the translated strings.

```
// Set the locale in the consumer application
MyPackage.setLocale('ar');

// Use the methods from your package to get translated strings
String helloMessage = MyPackage.getHelloMessage();
print(helloMessage); // Output: مرحبا
```

Answer (score -3):

In order to generate localization files inside a package:

1. Create localization files in .arb format
2. add l10n.yaml file inside the root folder of the package with these settings:

```
# Where to find translation files
arb-dir: lib/l10n

# Which translation is the default/template
template-arb-file: app_en.arb

# What to call generated dart files
output-localization-file: app_localizations.dart
```

3. make sure your main localization file and the 'template-arb-file' names are the same
4. update 'dependencies' and 'flutter' in pubspec.yaml file of the package as below:

```
dependencies:
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  intl: ^0.17.0


flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  generate: true
```

5. run 'flutter pub get' inside the package root location
6. Wrap your main UI widget with a MaterialApp
7. Update MaterialApp as below

```
MaterialApp(
              localizationsDelegates: AppLocalizations.localizationsDelegates,
              supportedLocales: AppLocalizations.supportedLocales,
      ),
```

8. Call the localization key inside a widget:

```
Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.helloWorld)
```

Note: Basically do almost same steps in official documentation inside your package root folder with a Custom MaterialApp
https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization

Comment: This is not very useful, as you're most likely _not_ going to use `MaterialApp` widget inside a package.

Comment: @albru123 have you found any solutions